# Install Ansible on CentOS 8 if you get ansible-core >= 2.12.2 with ansible-core < 2.13

Tags: ansible, centos8, epel

In order to install Ansible on Centos 8; epel-release package needs to be installed. Due to Centos8 end of life, no new packages and security updates are not maintained and all repos has moved under vault.centos.org thus CentOS-* repos need to replace then we can install epel-release. Once you install epel-release ansilbe installation gives below error since June 2022.

> - nothing provides (ansible-core >= 2.12.2 with ansible-core < 2.13) needed by ansible-5.4.0-2.el8.noarch
>   (try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages or '--nobest' to use not only best candidate packages)

Comment: The recommended way to install Ansible is through pip, not through the OS package manager: https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/installation_guide/intro_installation.html

Answer (score 2):

The solutions for that I have created a small script it changes centos-repos and install epel-relase then changes epel's repo and install Ansible 2.9.27-1.el8 with all dependencies.

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -ex

# Add EPEL repository

osV=$(rpm --eval '%{centos_ver}')

if [ "$osV" == "8" ]; then
    cd /etc/yum.repos.d/
    sudo sed -i 's/mirrorlist/#mirrorlist/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*
    sudo sed -i 's|#baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org|baseurl=http://vault.centos.org|g' /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-*

    sudo yum install -y epel-release
    sudo sed -i 's/metalink/#metalink/g' /etc/yum.repos.d/epel*
    sudo sed -i 's|#baseurl=https://download.example/pub/|baseurl=https://mirror.init7.net/fedora/|g' /etc/yum.repos.d/epel*
else
   sudo yum install -y epel-release
fi

sudo yum install -y ansible
```

Answer (score 0):

I also stucked by this question,and centos version was 8.5.2111 (*not centos stream*)

and i just manually download ansible-core.rpm and it's dependency and install them,

then i can install the ansible by `dnf install ansible`

the detail step was:

```
wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8-stream/AppStream/x86_64/os/Packages/ansible-core-2.12.2-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8-stream/AppStream/aarch64/os/Packages/python38-resolvelib-0.5.4-5.el8.noarch.rpm
wget http://mirror.centos.org/centos/8-stream/AppStream/x86_64/os/Packages/sshpass-1.09-4.el8.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh python38-resolvelib-0.5.4-5.el8.noarch.rpm
rpm -ivh sshpass-1.09-4.el8.x86_64.rpm
rpm -ivh ansible-core-2.12.2-3.el8.x86_64.rpm
```